# Can i send full store object from container to action creator (React/Redux)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, redux

Guys i don`t fully understand if this correct solution, but can i send some specific store Array[Object] from container to Action creator?

Task is to implement search in store.

Example of action creator

```
export const mySearch = (search) => {
return {
 type: SEARCH,
 a: data.text, //some additional value
 b: data.items //store object
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could apply some data from your store to the properties of your component.

```
const mapeStateToProps = state => ({ data: state.data });
```

From there you create your action by a "higher order function", passing your property in.

```
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  const mySearch = data => search => dispatch({
    type: SEARCH,
    a: data.text,
    b: data.items,
  });

  return { mySearch };
};
```

Now call it from your component.

```
const Component = props =>
  <input type="search" onUpdate={props.mySearch(props.data)} />;
```

You can get the value of the input by your search parameter: `search.target.value`

Answer (score 1):

If you're using redux-thunk, you could do it like

```
export const mySearch = (search) => {
return (dispatch, getState) => {

  const state = getState(); // <-- This will be your state tree
  const data = state.data; //  <-- or whatever path you have in your state

  // Now instead of return, dispatch it.
  dispatch({
    type: SEARCH,
    a: data.text,
    b: data.items
  });
}
```